# Realtime low pass filtering of wav files or raw input audio and simultaneous playback in Python

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, subprocess, signal-processing, wave

I want to perform low pass filtering of audio data in Python and play it back at the same time. I am looking for advice on improving my code, and I'll share my current but the very incomplete solution to the problem. Although I am requesting advice on improving it, I will not be completely rewriting all of the code. I want to use this as an opportunity to learn the low-level basics of signal processing, while at the same time getting to know Python 3 better. I'm comfortable with Python's syntax in general, but I've likely overlooked quite a few ways to do things more efficiently.

I'll provide the most important bits of the program's code below. My code is at the very least loosely based around answers I read on here, as well as some of my own ideas (such as the ring buffer). Although my primary objective is to get help, there is another reason I am writing this. As thanks for the information this community has provided me, I will give back what I know now in the hope that having it all in one place will help someone else wanting to do the same or a similar objective. The script is detailed below.

First, the necessary built-in modules are loaded.

```
import sys, wave, math, subprocess
```

A few global variables are declared and initialized. This is important that they are global because the data needs to persist between calls of the filter function. The clamp function is VERY important because, without it, conversion back to s16le from signed int will fail with an overflow error. I also need to load aplay as a subprocess to send the raw s16le samples to after processing. I chose aplay as the method of outputting sound because it conveniently buffers data itself, and is super simple to use, because you just pipe data to it.

```
aplay=subprocess.Popen(('aplay','-f','cd'),stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
source=wave.open(sys.argv[1],"rb")
frameRate=source.getframerate()
frequencyRatio=(int(sys.argv[2])/frameRate)
global windowSize
windowSize=int(math.sqrt(0.196196+frequencyRatio**2)/frequencyRatio)
global bufferIndex0; bufferIndex0=0
global bufferL0; bufferL0=[]
global bufferR0; bufferR0=[]
for _ in range(windowSize+1):
    bufferL0.append(0); bufferR0.append(0
clamp = lambda n, minn, maxn: max(min(maxn, n), minn)
```

Next, the wave file is loaded into memory as "data", and "data" is ripped apart and split into discrete frames stored as the frame[] array. The "data" object/variable is now useless and likely occupies 1GB or more RAM, so it gets nuked with "del data". Then, the frame data is looped over and is converted to signed 16-bit integers. It gets passed to the rolling average function. As you can see I have three copies of it to achieve the amount of frequency cutoff I wanted. I also avoided storing data in variables as much as possible, and it greatly reduced memory consumption and sped my code up a lot. That took it from stuttering to playing smoothly, but while consuming nearly all available processing power on one core.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    length=source.getnframes()
    data=source.readframes(length)
    frame=[data[_:_+4] for _ in range(0,len(data),4)]
    del data
    channel=[]
    for _ in range(length):
        channel=rollingAverage_stage2(rollingAverage_stage1(rollingAverage_stage0([int.from_bytes(frame[_][:2], byteorder='little', signed=True),int.from_bytes(frame[_][2:], byteorder='little', signed=True)])))
        aplay.stdin.write(bytearray(channel[0].to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)+channel[1].to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)))
```

The "rollingAverage" function is detailed here. I'm obviously only showing one copy as they're all the same except for variable names. Additional globals ringIndex1, ringIndex2, bufferL1, bufferL2, bufferR1, and bufferR2 are each declared at the beginning of the script and in the respective functions. Perhaps dynamically creating the variables and some instances of a "rollingAverage" class based on a number of passes input parameter would be a better idea, rather than three fixed copies.

```
def rollingAverage_stage0(channel):
    global bufferL0; global bufferR0; global ringIndex0
    bufferL0[ringIndex0],bufferR0[ringIndex0]=channel[0],channel[1]
    channel=[clamp(int(sum(bufferL0)/windowSize),-32768,32767),clamp(int(sum(bufferR0)/windowSize),-32768,32767)]
    if ringIndex0==windowSize:
        ringIndex0=0
    else:
        ringIndex0+=1
    return channel
```

That sums up the code. It works surprisingly well for low cutoff frequencies (Ex: 500) but clips the audio quite a bit when used with cutoff frequencies over 5000Hz. Not an issue for my use as I intend to cut off frequencies to the voice band, which is 3000Hz and lower, and I may go for 2000Hz and lower. My final script will read raw frames from rtl_sdr, using a subprocess pipe. The program will be used like so:

```
lowfilter.py <parameters>
```

rtl_sdr is a command that controls and grabs data from USB Realtek RTL2832 based software controlled radios. I might also throw a sox subprocess in the script to perform noise reduction.

Like I mentioned earlier, I very likely won't completely rewrite the program, but a heavy modification that comes close to a complete rewrite is definitely in the plan. I've spent several days on it so far and learned quite a bit in the process.

The audio I intend to process will be NOAA Weather Radio and similar low bandwidth FM transmissions. I will also be implementing some sort of automatic gain control and dynamic range compression if possible, but for now, filtering is good enough and it's where I'm going to keep my goal at. This is as much of something I want to achieve, as it is a reason to learn more about Python.

Maybe some things could be adapted to coroutines and generators for less resource usage. I don't understand them well, if at all, but I'm willing to learn. It seems they may be highly applicable to this application. Any modifications I make would be preferable with no additional libraries, besides perhaps numpy and something for multithreading. I don't understand numpy either, so that would be completely new to me. Links to the best resources for beginners would help, as even some of the examples I found for low pass filtering and the like were WAY beyond what I could figure out. That's why I write my own low pass filtering. Numpy is likely a lot faster than the builtin math library, so that's my second focus.

My current and primary focus is optimizing and load balancing. By splitting my script into different files, and launching them with subprocess.Popen, I can have them run as separate processes. This will inevitably cause them to be put on separate cores by the kernel. This means I can send large blobs of data to stdin, and immediately after taking the last blob of data the subprocess dumped to stdout and pass it on to the next sub-process. This could even be done in a bash script instead of the main python script. The result of such an optimization would mean the main script spends most of its time just shuffling data around, and would result in a massive performance increase.

Whatever advice you have, I'd like to hear it.

(Note to whoever suggested edits: Thank you for the help improving the grammar and spelling in my question. Please note the name rollingAverage should be kept as is, because it's the name of a function, and subprocess.Popen is not a missing space between sentances.)

Answer (score 0):

I have received help from someone on this topic and I also spent the past few days doing some of my own research. The answer to my question (currently) is as follows:

Multithreading IS absolutely necessary for this application, and I have found a very reasonable way to implement it without having to deal with the Global Interpreter Locks. I split the functionality of the script up into several files, and they stream data to each other over sockets on localhost. As only 1 way communication was required, no special IPC had to be implemented, raw data was simply sent between the scripts.

The code for input.py, which loads the WAV file (and will soon be grabbing data from a command that gets raw audio from a USB SDR instead) is listed here. Comments describing each step have been added to the code for clarity.

input.py:

```
#!/bin/env python3
# Low pass filter written in python3
# (C) TheNH813 2018
# License: WTFPLv2

# Import sys for argv[], wave for io, socket for threads
import sys, wave, socket

# Start listener server on localhost:37420
listener=socket.socket()
listener.bind(("localhost",37420))
listener.listen()
# Load the file specified in argv[1] into data
source=wave.open(sys.argv[1],"rb")
data=source.readframes(source.getnframes())
# Split the frames into an array from frames
frame=[data[_:_+4] for _ in range(0,len(data),4)]
# Delete data because we have everything we need in frame[]
del data

while True:
    # Accept incoming connections, execution stops until a connection is made
    network,address=listener.accept()
    # Let user know it's working and sending data
    print("inputServer: Sending data")
    try:
        # Attempt to send data until it's all sent
        for _ in range(source.getnframes()):
            network.send(frame[_])
    # Trap all errors and restart if something goes wrong
    except BaseException as ded:
        # Let user know server encountered error or connection died
        print("inputServer: "+str(ded))
```

The code which performs the filtering, and no longer depends on a bunch of globals is listed here. Some optimizations have been made, such as mutating the ringBuffer arrays in place instead of passing them back and forth. I had no idea this was possible before I started. The data is sent through a simple rolling average filter in multiple stages to get a VERY sharp filter cutoff. For my intended application, this is what I need, simply removing or adding a pass or two will lessen or strengthen the effect. After it's finished processing, the data gets sent off in blocks of 65535 frames to the final script which plays it back. I chose 65535 for no reason other then a buffer over 1 second was desired, and I like powers of 2. The code is here.

lowpass.py:

```
#!/bin/env python3
# Low pass filter written in python3
# (C) TheNH813 2018
# License: WTFPLv2

# Import sys for argv[], socket for multithreading, math for sqrt and sum
import sys, socket, math

# Calculating the frequency ratio is necessary for calculating window length
# Change 44100 if your sample rate is different, or get as aparameter with sys.argv[]
frequencyRatio=int(sys.argv[1])/44100
windowSize=int(math.sqrt(0.196196+frequencyRatio**2)/frequencyRatio)
# This function is necessary to clamp the output value to the 16 bit signed limits
clamp = lambda n, minn, maxn: max(min(maxn, n), minn)

# This function perform the actual filtering
def lowPassFilter(channel,ringBuffer,ringIndex):
    # Set the current index of the ring buffer to the input
    ringBuffer[ringIndex]=channel
    # Average the contents of the ring buffer
    channel=int(sum(ringBuffer)/windowSize)
    # Check if ring buffer has reached end
    if ringIndex==windowSize:
        # If it has, reset index to 0
        ringIndex=0
    else:
        # Otherwise, increment by 1
        ringIndex+=1
    # Return the processed sample and current buffer position
    return channel,ringIndex

# Define the ring buffers
ringBuffer0L=[]
for _ in range(windowSize+1):
    ringBuffer0L.append(0)
# Copying is faster the iterating again
ringBuffer0R=ringBuffer0L.copy()
ringBuffer1L=ringBuffer0L.copy()
ringBuffer1R=ringBuffer0L.copy()
ringBuffer2L=ringBuffer0L.copy()
ringBuffer2R=ringBuffer0L.copy()
# Define the ring buffer indexes
ringIndex0L=0
ringIndex0R=0
ringIndex1L=0
ringIndex1R=0
ringIndex2L=0
ringIndex2R=0

# Start the server on localhost:37421, and recieve from localhost:37420
listener=socket.socket()
listener.bind(("localhost",37421))
listener.listen()
stream=socket.socket()
stream.connect(("localhost",37420))

while True:
    # Accept incoming connections
    network,address=listener.accept()
    # Let the user know it's started and working
    print("filterServer: Began sending data to "+str(address))
    try:
        # Keep looping forever unless error occurs
        while True:
            # Clear array
            frame=[]
            # Load data into array as buffer
            for _ in range(65535):
                frame.append(stream.recv(4))
            # Perform digital signal processing
            for _ in range(65535):
                # Split each frame into the left and right channels as integers
                channel=[int.from_bytes(frame[_][:2], byteorder='little',signed=True),int.from_bytes(frame[_][2:],byteorder='little',signed=True)]
                # Perform low pass filter on left channel
                channel[0],ringIndex0L=lowPassFilter(channel[0],ringBuffer0L,ringIndex0L)
                # Perform low pass filter on left channel (again)
                channel[0],ringIndex1L=lowPassFilter(channel[0],ringBuffer1L,ringIndex1L)
                # Perform low pass filter on left channel (again)
                channel[0],ringIndex2L=lowPassFilter(channel[0],ringBuffer2L,ringIndex2L)
                # Clamp left channel so it dosen't go out of bounds and cause a over/underflow error
                channel[0]=clamp(channel[0],-32768,32767)
                # Perform low pass filter on left channel
                channel[1],ringIndex0R=lowPassFilter(channel[1],ringBuffer0R,ringIndex0R)
                # Perform low pass filter on right channel (again)
                channel[1],ringIndex1R=lowPassFilter(channel[1],ringBuffer1R,ringIndex1R)
                # Perform low pass filter on right channel (again)
                channel[1],ringIndex2R=lowPassFilter(channel[1],ringBuffer2R,ringIndex2R)
                # Clamp rihgt channel so it dosen't go out of bounds and cause a over/underflow error
                channel[1]=clamp(channel[1],-32768,32767)
                # Join the integers back into a single binary frame
                frame[_]=bytearray(channel[0].to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True)+channel[1].to_bytes(2, byteorder='little', signed=True))
            # Iterate through processed data
            for data in frame:
                # Send it off to the playback script
                network.send(data)
    except BaseException as ded:
        # Let the user know if the server dies or encountered a error
        print("filterServer: "+str(ded))
```

Finally, we take the raw data, and throw it at aplay, which buffers it and writes it to the sound card. This only works on Linux or other systems with ALSA installed.

player.py:

```
#!/bin/env python3
# Low pass filter written in python3
# (C) TheNH813 2018
# License: WTFPLv2

# Import socket for multithreading, subprocess for audio output
import socket, subprocess

# Connect to the filter server and recieve the packets
stream=socket.socket()
stream.connect(("localhost",37421))
# Launch aplay subprocess and have it ready to play audio
aplay=subprocess.Popen('aplay -f cd'.split(),stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

# Infinite loop
while True:
    # Clear data buffer
    data=[]
    # Fill buffer with data from server
    for _ in range(65535):
        # Request a frame of audio
        data.append(stream.recv(4))
    # Iterate through data
    for frame in data:
        # Play the frames of audio
        aplay.stdin.write(frame)
```

I'm sure there's more I can do to improve the performance of the code, but I'm happy with this for now. I will continue to apply what I learn to improving this script, however, this version I posted here (the current version), is far more then enough to answer my original question. I am providing this information in the hopes that it will be able to help someone else.

You can use that code for whatever, I hereby release it under the WTFPLv2.

Comment: If you're curious about the discussion where I as advised on my code:
[reddit.com/r/learnpython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8u4ahx/realtime_low_pass_filtering_of_wav_files_or_raw/)